# Tracking managed package in source control

Tags: salesforcedx, managed-package, appexchange, vs-code, git

I have a managed package that I am testing in my sandbox from the App Exchange. I am also writing some custom classes that depend on resources in this managed package. I want to track these changes in my repository in order to promote this to higher environments. Are there any best practices for tracking managed packages in a git repo? Should I only pull down the resources my custom code depends on? Is there an SFDX command that would pull the entire package down into my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only track your source code (the custom classes) that you have created in your git repo. The managed package being installed is then just a pre-requisite of being able to deploy your code.

The install of a managed package can be scripted:

```
sfdx force:package:install --package <<version id>> --installationkey <<password>> --wait 20
```

and running that can be documented as a pre-requisite.